# Python for loop iterating 'i'

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary

I am using the following script:

```
tagRequest = requests.get("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/" + tag + "/media/recent?client_id=" + clientId)
tagData = json.loads(tagRequest.text)
tagId = tagData["data"][0]["user"]["id"]

for i in tagData["data"]:
    print tagData["data"][i]
```

My script is supposed to iterate over the JSON object, tagData. (Over everything in "data".) However, I am getting the following error: `list indices must be integers, not dict.`

Comment: either `print i` or iterate over range

Comment: print your tagData and post it up

Comment: @Aero don't forget to accept an answer (the check-mark symbol next to the answer you choose)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are iterating over the contents of `tagData['data']` not its indices, so:

```
for i in tagData["data"]:
    print i
```

Or indices:

```
for i in xrange(len(tagData["data"])):
    print tagData["data"][i]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use enumerate(iterable) you can access the index and the foreach item:

```
for i,item in enumerate(tagData["data"]):
    print i
    print item
```